# using two variables in a function from different controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function in which I want to use a variable from a different view controller and a variable defined within the function. The variable from the different view controller is being sent to the second view controller with the following code:

```
func clock(){

    time++

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("timerValID", object: time)

}


@IBAction func TimerGo(sender: AnyObject) {


    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: ("clock"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}
```

The code from the second view controller (function containing two variables) is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("location:"), name: "timerValID", object: self.view.window)}


func location(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)(notification: NSNotification){

    var startlocation: CLLocation!
    var lastlocation: CLLocation!
    var traveleddistance: Double = 0
    var speed:CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()
    let time = notification.object as! NSNumber
```

}

When I run the app, I get the message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: unrecognized selector sent to instance.....

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the error is the part you missed and replaced with ".....". It would tell you which selector was the problem.

Nevertheless, looking at your code, there are a couple of problems.

Firstly, with Swift, you don't use `Selector("myFunc")`, you just use "myFunc". Also, the "object:" parameter is the source of the notification. In most cases you will use "nil" for "any source of this message". So therefore you would have

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
             selector: "location:", name: "timerValID", object: nil)
     }
```

Secondly, your addObserver function will be passed just one object, which is the notification. Therefore, the signature for "location:" should be

```
    func location(notification: NSNotification){     
        //do stuff
    }
```

This is probably the cause of the error you are seeing, because you don't have a method with the expected signature.

Comment: If I use the code func location(notification: NSNotification){     
        //do stuff
    } will I still be able to access the CLLocation manager?

Comment: Where is the location manager coming from? The function you are referencing is on `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. So where you create the manager you should be setting it's delegate to something that implements this protocol. You seem to want to respond to some timer event and also location changes - these are separate things that need their own code.